# Insert & Symbol in Textview android:text

Tags: android, android-layout

How can I insert `&` Symbol in `<TextView>`
I have tried with & and Hex code but not allow me to do this.

```
<TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#49515F"
    android:text="Mission and Philosophy" // & 
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="11dp" 
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I know if you externalize the string to string.xml you can definitely use `&amp;` to achieve the desired result. The same should work inline.

```
 <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:textColor="#49515F"
                  android:text="Mission &amp; Philosophy" 
                  android:textStyle="bold"
                  android:textSize="11dp" 
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
```

or

```
 <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                  android:textColor="#49515F"
                  android:text="@string/mission_philosophy" 
                  android:textStyle="bold"
                  android:textSize="11dp" 
                  android:layout_width="wrap_content" />
```

Then in `strings.xml` or really any `xml` file under `res\values` folder do:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <string name="mission_philosophy">Mission &amp; Philosophy</string>
</resources>
```

The second approach is more desirable because *if* you never need to localize the app, all your strings will be in one xml file.

Comment: `<u>Mission &amp; Philosopy</u>` take a look at the [Formatting and Styling](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource.html) section to see what all is possible. You can even have links in your text. You _may_ have to put the text through an html parser depending on what you're doing.

Comment: Try `\u0026` which is unicode for &. You might need to escape `\` i.e. `\\u0026`

Answer (score 1):

please try this,

```
 android:text="Mission &amp; Philosophy"
```

It is called Escape Sequence.

Comment: Escape sequence are working at run-time in java or c code. not in XML.. because as per my knowledge its Parent  is lang library so it is understand Escape sequence but here is XML code which not recognize it.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the ampersand followed by amp and then a semi colon?  I cannot do it here because the web site converts it.

Answer (score 0):

Use \u0026 in Unicode for "&"

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="1 * * * \u0026" />
```

Output: 1 * * * &